# How do I change Bulma's default styling?

Tags: css, sass, bulma

I've installed `sass` as instructed here http://versions.bulma.io/0.7.0/documentation/components/navbar/#variables. The guide says I need to include my change from `$navbar-item-hover-background-color: $background` to `$navbar-item-hover-background-color: #28567d` before `bulma.sass` gets imported.

I haven't seen a line with `@import bulma.sass` or `@import bulma` on it though.

the directory tree may be helpful:

```
.
├── bulma.sass
├── CHANGELOG.md
├── css
│   ├── bulma.css
│   └── bulma.css.map
├── LICENSE
├── package.json
├── README.md
└── sass
    ├── base
    │   ├── _all.sass
    │   ├── generic.sass
    │   ├── helpers.sass
    │   └── minireset.sass
    ├── components
    │   ├── _all.sass
    │   ├── breadcrumb.sass
    │   ├── card.sass
    │   ├── dropdown.sass
    │   ├── level.sass
    │   ├── media.sass
    │   ├── menu.sass
    │   ├── message.sass
    │   ├── modal.sass
    │   ├── navbar.sass
    │   ├── pagination.sass
    │   ├── panel.sass
    │   └── tabs.sass
    ├── elements
    │   ├── _all.sass
    │   ├── box.sass
    │   ├── button.sass
    │   ├── container.sass
    │   ├── content.sass
    │   ├── form.sass
    │   ├── icon.sass
    │   ├── image.sass
    │   ├── notification.sass
    │   ├── other.sass
    │   ├── progress.sass
    │   ├── table.sass
    │   ├── tag.sass
    │   └── title.sass
    ├── grid
    │   ├── _all.sass
    │   ├── columns.sass
    │   └── tiles.sass
    ├── layout
    │   ├── _all.sass
    │   ├── footer.sass
    │   ├── hero.sass
    │   └── section.sass
    └── utilities
        ├── _all.sass
        ├── animations.sass
        ├── controls.sass
        ├── derived-variables.sass
        ├── functions.sass
        ├── initial-variables.sass
        └── mixins.sass
```

I've tried to edit `navbar.sass`:

`$navbar-item-hover-background-color: #28567d !default`

and then rebuild the `bulma.css` file with `sass bulma.sass bulma.css`

It had no effect though.

Any assistance much appreciated.